# Why am I being told that "textField" is private API?

Tags: iphone, ios

I submitted my application for review on the App Store, and it was rejected for the use of private API.  I was told that I was using the private API for `textField`, but I see that UITextField has a documented method named `textField`.

Why is my code being marked as using private API and what can I do about it?

Comment: You'll need to provide more info than that.

Answer (score 2):

`textField` was a private, Apple-only method until iOS 5.0. If your application utilizes the `textField` method and supports anything below iOS 5, you're likely to run into problems in both support for the feature on individual devices as well as with Apple's App Store review team.

Comment: Hi, esqew. You means "textField" is a method? but in my code, I just use  it as a variable name in UITextField delegate methods.

Comment: @SamNiu - Odds are, this is just a false positive in their private API scanner.  It's picking up the symbol of `textField` in your code, and it doesn't know enough to distinguish between a method and your variable.  The easy solution would be to rename your variable, but I'd also let them know that their scanner is picking this up wrongly, so that they can fix whatever's triggering this.